# AngularJS manipulate two ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm calling two times the same list in my HTML5 view.

```
<div class="list" data-ng-repeat="item in model.items">
    <div class=list-item">
       {{ item.name }} 
        <a data-ng-click="addToList(item)">
            <span data-ng-hide="item.checked">Add</span>
            <span data-ng-show="item.checked">Remove</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="checkbox-list" data-ng-repeat="item in model.items">
    <div class=list-item">
       <input type="checkbox" data-ng-checked="item.checked" data-ng-click="addToList(item)" />
       {{ item.name }} 
    </div>
</div>
```

In my controller, I'm having the method defined in the scope:

```
function addToList(item) {
    item.checked = !item.checked;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.$scope.items.length; i++) {
        if (this.$scope.items.id == item.id) {
            this.$scope.items[i] = item;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the `Add`or `Remove` button, the list has an update, but the checkbox-list item doesn't get checked.

On the other hand, when `checking` a `checkbox`, the list doesn't get an update.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: what do you mean by `this.$scope.items`?

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: This works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, This is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are mixing the javascript function declaration syntax with angular

While working with angular you should always angular syntax to get the benefit of synchronization between the model and the view.
    $scope.addToList = function(){}

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  
  $scope.model = {};
  
  $scope.model.items = [{"name":"one"},{"name":"two"}]
  
  
  $scope.addToList = function(item) {
    item.checked = !item.checked;
  }
  
  
  
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    <div class="list" data-ng-repeat="item in model.items">
    <div class="list-item">
       {{ item.name }} 
        <a data-ng-click="addToList(item)">
            <span data-ng-hide="item.checked">Add</span>
            <span data-ng-show="item.checked">Remove</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="checkbox-list" data-ng-repeat="item in model.items">
    <div class="list-item">
       <input type="checkbox" data-ng-checked="item.checked" data-ng-click="addToList(item)" />
       {{ item.name }} 
    </div>
</div>


    
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've tried this solution, but there isn't any change in my code.

Comment: No change in your code means  , you were already using this syntax or no change in the result?

Comment: SO snippet provided in solution works fine. could you check if that is what you are expecting ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using `controller as` syntax.

So in your js code add the model to the controller itself(assuming you `yourController` refers to the controller and you have your methods in the controller):

```
  for (var i = 0; i < yourController.items.length; i++) {
    if (yourController.items.id == item.id) {
        yourController.items[i] = extension;
        break;
    }
  }
```

Inside `YourController` declare:

```
var yourController = this;
```

Then in the HTML where you declare the controller, declare it as follows:

```
 ng-controller = "YourController as yourController"
```

And then you can access the items in HTML as:

```
yourController.items
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using function with $scope. This might help:

```
$scope.addToList = function (item) {
    item.checked = !item.checked;

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.items.id == item.id) {
            $scope.items[i] = extension;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```